# Непонятное поведение вменённого this

Tags: javascript

```js
x = {}

function f1() {
  this.v1 = 'cool'
  try {
    console.log('v1:', v1)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error')
  }
}

f1.bind(x)()
f1()
f1.bind(x)()
f1()
```

#### Вывод:

```
error
v1: cool
v1: cool
v1: cool
```

Объясните почему этот код выдаёт `error` сначала, а потом только `cool`.

Как вообще получается что `v1` может обходиться без `this` в некотором случае?

Comment: насчет v1 без this - когда вы вызываете функцию без bind(x), this ссылается на window (или какой там у вас Global scope), и v1 становится глобальной переменной,и поэтому доступна без this

Comment: Странно почему пометили этот вопрос как дубликат, в то время как он задан на год раньше чем референтный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что во втором вызове this - это window. Начиная с этого момента существует глобальная переменная v1.